# How to create temporary dataframe from a dataframe in pyspark?

Tags: pyspark

I need to create temporary dataframe from a dataframe based on some condition in pyspark. Could you please help me how to do this?

Example:

df:

```
id  Name   last_name
101 Ram    Kumar
102 Shyam  Naresh
103 Akash  Gupta
```

I want to create temporary dataframe based on id value.
suppose id = 101

then temp_df:

```
id    Name  last_name
101   Ram   Kumar
```

Answer (score 0):

use `filter` condition to create temp_df.

**`Example:`**

```
temp_df=df.filter(col("id")==101)
temp_df.show()
#+---+----+---------+
#| id|name|last_name|
#+---+----+---------+
#|101| Ram|    Kumar|
#+---+----+---------+
```

Alternatively you can use **`createOrReplaceTempView`** then use sql to filter out the required data.

**`Example:`**

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView("tmp")
temp_df=sql("select * from tmp where id =101")
temp_df.show()
#+---+----+---------+
#| id|name|last_name|
#+---+----+---------+
#|101| Ram|    Kumar|
#+---+----+---------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a SQL string to filter your dataframe:

```
temp_df = df.filter('id = 101')
```